# Javascript onclick with array parameters

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, parameters

I'm trying to figure out how to make the following code work:

```
<ul> 
    <li id='anvil1' class='locked' onclick='anvil1.countCheck("anvil1", "defense", 10, event.button);'>+10 Defensive Ability</li>
    <li id='anvil4' class='locked' onclick='anvil4.countCheck("anvil4", "[\"defense\", \"constitution\"]", [10, 20], event.button);'>+15 Defensive Ability <br />+20 Constitution</li> 
</ul>
```

These links are accessing methods from the the star object. I need the 2nd and 3rd parameters to be arrays, because they have a variable number of values. For instance, the first star, anvil1, has one stat (defense) and one value (10). The fourth star has two stats (defense, constitution) and two values (10, 20). I believe the number of stats/values can go up to 3.

So far, if I try to call `stats[0]` the value that's returned is simply the first letter?

`alert('Stats: ' + stats[0]);` results in an alert box with `Stats: d` or `Stats: [`

I'm not sure how to fix this, and any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you escaping `"` when in between `'`s. In any case, I would recommend adding the events _in JavaScript_. Check `addEventListener`

Comment: You are not passing an array with `"[\"defense\", \"constitution\"]"` but a string. Why not do it like you did for the 3rd parameter ? `[\"defense\", \"constitution\"]` `<-` this is an array. And this is why `stats[0]` is `[` (first character in the string).

Comment: I just tried everything I could think of to get it to work - " " like in the first example, [ ] (not shown), [\" "\], might have been a few others.

You're suggesting I remove the 'onclick' section and instead use an event listener to call the functions?

Comment: @PinkTurtle [\"defense\", \"constitution\"] gives a syntax error.

Comment: See my answer I made a typo indeed. It should have been `["defense", "constitution"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you spot the difference ?

```
"[\"defense\", \"constitution\"]"
```

is a string and

```
[10, 20]
```

is an array. Obviously you want your 2nd parameter as an array too so you need to change your call to

```
anvil4.countCheck("anvil4", ["defense", "constitution"], [10, 20], event.button);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have your array in quotes. when you use [n] on a string it returns the n'th character. you can also get rid of the string escapes (like elclanrs said)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't pass the parameters like that. You could add one eventlistener for anvil elements and pass the parameters with data attributes.

Please have a look at the following snippet or in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/5efxow2v/).

```js
var anvil = {
 countCheck: function(e) {
   var props = this.dataset.props.split(','),
      points = this.dataset.points.split(',');
    
    console.log(this.id, props, points);
  }
}


// add eventlisteners
var anvils = document.getElementsByClassName('anvil');

for (var i=0; i< anvils.length; i++) {
 anvils[i].addEventListener('click', anvil.countCheck);
}
```

```html
<ul> 
    <li id='anvil1' class='anvil locked' data-props="defense" data-points="10">+10 Defensive Ability</li>
    <li id='anvil4' class='anvil locked' data-props="defense,constitution" data-points="10,20">+15 Defensive Ability <br />+20 Constitution</li> 
</ul>
```